# In one table Manager ID and Cashier ID is available and in another table Cashier ID, Manager ID are available

Tags: sql, oracle

In table1 Manager ID and Cashier ID are available, and in another table2 Cashier ID and Manager ID are available in one Column and and their names in another Column.

How do I get the names and ID separately in one query?

```
Table 1 
----------------
Column1 : Manager ID
Column2 : Cashier ID 

Table 2
-----------------

Column1 : Employee ID (it contains both manager and cashier ID)
Column2 : Employee Names (it contains both manager and cashier Name)
```

Expected result:

```
Column1: Manager ID
Column2: Manager Name
Column3: Cashier ID
Column4: Cashier Name
```

How do I get this result?

Comment: All you have to do is join to the second table twice, once on each ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, both managers (identified by `manager_id` in `TABLE1`) and cashiers (identified by `cashier_id` in `TABLE1`) are *employees* (identified by `employee_id` in `TABLE2`) -- that is, it isn't the case that one value of `employee_ID` contains values for both `manager_ID` and `cashier_ID`. With that assumption in mind, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
SELECT t1.manager_id, t2a.employee_name AS manager_name
     , t1.cashier_id, t2b.employee_name AS cashier_name
  FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2a
    ON t1.manager_id = t2a.employee_id
 INNER JOIN table2 t2b
    ON t1.cashier_id = t2b.employee_id;
```

Note that what I am doing above is joining to `TABLE2` *twice* but with different aliases. Now, if there are employees that are cashiers but who don't have managers, then you'll want to use a `LEFT JOIN` in place of the first `INNER JOIN`. And if there are managers you want to return but who don't have cashiers working under them, then you'll want to use a `LEFT JOIN` in place of the *second* `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.ID_STR_RT,
  LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.ID_WS,
  LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.DC_DY_BSN,
  LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.AI_TRN,
  TR_LTM_SLS_RTN.ID_ITM,
  LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.DE_RS,
  --LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.ID_MGR,
  --PA_EM.NM_EM,
  LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.LOGIN_ID
FROM LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD
INNER JOIN TR_LTM_SLS_RTN
ON LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.AI_TRN = TR_LTM_SLS_RTN.AI_TRN
JOIN TR_LTM_RTL_TRN
ON TR_LTM_RTL_TRN.AI_TRN = TR_LTM_SLS_RTN.AI_TRN
JOIN PA_EM
ON PA_EM.ID_EM                       = LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.ID_MGR
WHERE LS_ACS_MGR_OVRD.DE_RS          ='Layaway Delete'
AND TR_LTM_RTL_TRN.FL_VD_LN_ITM NOT IN (1) ;

Comment: In the above query I need to add Names of Manager and Cashier is it Possible... ?

Comment: @SreerangaVinjamuri, please update your question with the above code and format it properly and I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks For your Update, Now my problem is solved.. I applied the Query given by you is exactly correct.. Thanks for Helping me..

Answer (score 0):

For the IDs, if they are a fixed length, you can use the Substr function - http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php.

For the names, if they are separated by commas or semicolons or the like, you can use the Instr function - http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php

Comment: Have another look at the question, you've misunderstood that completely.